# Is schema.org's/Google Rich Snippet microformatting breaking HTML rules?

Tags: php, html, seo

According to [schema.org](http://schema.org), this is how you are supposed to mark up your html to make use of "rich snippet" metadata that is to be gobbled up by search engines:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
```

But `itemscope` on itself is invalid. It's a boolean value, not an attribute like `itemscope="true"`

I'm using PHPTAL and it refuses to process my page once it runs into this attribute. Other validators choke as well.

So is schema.org's specification just plain wrong?

Comment: It's valid html, guess you meant xhtml.

Comment: Yes, it seems itemscope="itemscope" is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a boolean attribute, which is perfectly acceptable in HTML5.

I expect that your parsers are just old.  The W3C validation service has no issues with schema.org's formats.

---

Added linky:  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute

---

Just to update this for posterity, the answer is to fully qualify boolean properties.  This means using a syntax like `itemscope="itemscope"`

Comment: OK, I'm not using HTML5. Now what?

Comment: Don't use schema.org's microformats.  Sometimes you can't have your cake and eat it too, unfortunately.  You could implement some flavor of RDFa/Dublin Core, which are older and designed for older parsers -- but Google/Bing will likely consider those dead code trees.  A lot of work for a short time window.

Comment: Actually... you should be able to use 'itemscope="itemscope"', which is how boolean attributes work (like selected on a `<select>`).

Comment: Fortunately the parser will accept itemscope="itemscope". http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: Sorry for missing that at first.  But +1 for pointing me at that tool...  I didn't know it existed.